# How to display values in JS from a PHP array that was posted from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button called `rename` that when pushed, executes in jQuery a `rename.php` file. Inside that php file the program selects data from a mysql, creates an array with that data, and processes an array in to `json_encode($array);`. How can I then get that json encoded array and echo it out into javascript?

I'm trying to echo the array out so that javascript displays my images src's.

This is my second line of ajax so I just wrote the javascript out as if it were php because I'm not sure of the commands or structure in js.

```
$.ajax
        (
            {
                url:"test4.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success:function(result)
                {
                    /*alert(result);*/
                    document.getElementById("images_to_rename").innerHTML = foreach(jArray as array_values) 
                    {
                        "<img src=\""array_values['original_path']"/"array_values['media']"/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

and my jQuery php file:

```
<?php
include 'db/mysqli_connect.php';
$username = "slick";
if(empty($_GET['image_name']))
{
    echo '<div class="refto" id="refto">image_name is empty</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div class="refto" id="refto">image_name is not empty</div>';
    foreach($_GET['image_name'] as $rowid_rename)
    {
        //echo '<br><p class="colourful">rowid_refto: '.$rowid_refto.'</p><br>';

        $active = 1;
        $command = "Rename";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".$username." SET active=?, command=? WHERE rowid=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("isi", $active, $command, $rowid_rename);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
                                                                                                //go to database, get parameters of sort
    $command = "Rename";
    $active = 1;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT original_path, media FROM " . $username . " WHERE active=? and command=?");            
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $active, $command);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $arri[] = $row;
    }
    foreach($arri as $rows)                                                                                         //put them into workable variables
    {
        $rowt = $rows['original_path'];
        $rowy = $rows['media'];
        //echo 'rows[\'original_path\'] = '.$rows['original_path'].''.$rows['media'].'';
    }
    $stmt->close();
    echo json_encode($arri);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($arri); ?>;

    </script>
    <?php


}       

echo "something2";
?>
```

My PHP file is a jQuery url:"test4.php", type: "GET", and is not the main file. The main file is called main.php and the test4.php is something that's called in jQuery when the user clicks on rename.

Somebody suggested console log so here's what chrome says:

```
<div class="refto" id="refto">image_name is not empty</div>[{"original_path":"Downloads","media":"shorter.jpg"},{"original_path":"Album 2","media":"balls.jpg"}]    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var jArray= [{"original_path":"Downloads","media":"shorter.jpg"},{"original_path":"Album 2","media":"balls.jpg"}];

    </script>
    something2
```

Comment: My PHP file is a jQuery `url:"test4.php",
     type: "GET",` and is not the main file. The main file is called main.php and the test4.php is something that's called in jQuery when the user clicks on `rename`.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax php  file isn't render in browser, then the variable jArray is undefined. With your case, let return php file to json and you can get it as variable in result.

```
    <?php
include 'db/mysqli_connect.php';
$username = "slick";
if (empty($_GET['image_name'])) {
    //echo '<div class="refto" id="refto">image_name is empty</div>';
} else {
    //echo '<div class="refto" id="refto">image_name is not empty</div>';
    foreach ($_GET['image_name'] as $rowid_rename) {
        //echo '<br><p class="colourful">rowid_refto: '.$rowid_refto.'</p><br>';

        $active = 1;
        $command = "Rename";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE " . $username . " SET active=?, command=? WHERE rowid=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("isi", $active, $command, $rowid_rename);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    //go to database, get parameters of sort
    $command = "Rename";
    $active = 1;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT original_path, media FROM " . $username . " WHERE active=? and command=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $active, $command);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arri[] = $row;
    }
    foreach ($arri as $rows) {                                                                                         //put them into workable variables
        $rowt = $rows['original_path'];
        $rowy = $rows['media'];
        //echo 'rows[\'original_path\'] = '.$rows['original_path'].''.$rows['media'].'';
    }
    $stmt->close();
    echo json_encode($arri);
    //stop render here
    die();
}
?>
```

php file need return only json string. Then we'll get result as json variable in javascript.

And Js:

```
$.ajax
    (
        {
            url:"test4.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success:function(result)
            {
                var jArray = JSON.parse(result);
                /*alert(result);*/
                var txt = "";
                jArray.forEach(function(array_values){
                    txt += `<img src=\""array_values.original_path."/"array_values.media"/>`;
                })  
                document.getElementById("images_to_rename").innerHTML = txt;
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: That didn't do anything too. The code seems to not work when I add the line: `var jArray = JSON.parse(result);`. Does this grab the `json_encoded` array from the result?

Comment: How can this work then if the php file won't register in the DOM?

Comment: I added the full jQuery php file. `Does alert(result) show the data?` It does, it shows the json_encoded data yea.

Comment: can you check header of response, if header is json, you don't need JSON.pares(result), let use jArray = result. Can yo show result `console.log(result)`?

Comment: How to check header? And I posted the console log of chrome in the question.

Comment: If you mean the header as in the address bar, it's not displaying a JSON encoded url when the user clicks on `rename`.

Comment: Still does nothning. Says that the `rename_image()` function is undefined. `rename_image()` is the name of my javascript call for the rename button.